# How do i get logback version 1.3.x

Tags: logback, slf4j

I'm having trouble in logback version up. (1.2.9 -> 1.3.4)

this is my build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')

//...

    testImplementation('org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.3')
    testImplementation('ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.3.4')
    testImplementation('ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.3.4')

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

The following error logs were found

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder`

There is no problem when 1.2.9, but I don't know why it is not work with 1.3.x

Answer (score 0):

SLF4J 2.0.0 incorporates an optional fluent api. Otherwise, there are no client facing API changes in 2.0.x. For most users, upgrading to version 2.0..x should be a drop-in replacement, as long as the logging provider is updated as well.

In version 2.0.0, SLF4J has been modularized per JPMS/Jigsaw specification. The JPMS module names are listed in another FAQ entry.

More visibly, slf4j-api now relies on the ServiceLoader mechanism to find its logging backend. SLF4J 1.7.x and earlier versions relied on the static binder mechanism which is no loger honored by slf4j-api version 2.0.x. More specifically, when initializing the LoggerFactory class will no longer search for the StaticLoggerBinder class on the class path.

Instead of "bindings" now org.slf4j.LoggerFactory searches for "providers". These ship for example with slf4j-nop-2.0.x.jar, slf4j-simple-2.0.x.jar or slf4j-jdk14-2.0.x.jar.

The following table describes the results when various slf4j-api and slf4j-simple versions are placed on the class path. Please note that the table below applies by analogy not just to slf4j-simple but also to other providers such as slf4j-reload4j, logback-classic, slf4j-jdk14, etc...
https://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#changesInVersion200